# How to write an ArrayList to an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I'm trying to store an `ArrayList` into an XML file so that I can retrieve the information later on and then display it back into the console.

Can someone show me the most effective way to do this?

EDIT:

Heres what I am trying to write into an external file

```
// new user is created
Bank bank = new Bank();

System.out.println("Enter your full name below (e.g. John M. Smith): ");
String name = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Create a username: ");
String userName = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter your starting deposit amount: ");
int balance = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.print(dash);
System.out.print("Generating your information...\n");
System.out.print(dash);

int pin = bank.PIN();
String accountNum = bank.accountNum();

User user = new User(name, userName, pin, accountNum, balance);

//new user gets added to the array list
Bank.users.add(user);

System.out.println(user);
```

This all creates a Bank user, which gets thrown into an `ArrayList`, then I want to store their information so that I can come back later and redisplay it.

Comment: Have you tried [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) ?

Comment: You could also use Java's serialization for this purpose, though the resulting file won't be an XML (i.e. you can use this if you only need to access the data in Java applications).

Comment: This question is too broad. An `ArrayList` of what? What XML schema?

Comment: @Njol I will be in the Java Application when I access this file, I need to store virtual bank account users into a file, and then be able to re-read them back into the program when they have a matching pin number and username...

Comment: @Njol I certainly do not have to use XML, someone in my previous post told me that it was the better way to go...

Comment: Since you're not wed to XML, I'd recommend using JSON and reading/writing with Jackson (or Gson).

Comment: @dnault the problem is that I dont even know that basics of even using the serializer... so if JSON is more complex then I dont think it would be the best option for me to go.

Comment: @ks23 JSON is pretty straightforward. Take a look at [GSON's user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). If you don't have to read the GSON yourself (JSON is human readable), it's even easier. Although personally, if that was the case, I'd just use [serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WriteFile ob = new WriteFile();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new details("A", 20, 1));
    list.add(new details("B", 30, 2));

    ob.writeXmlFile(list);
}
```

// Modify this below class as per your need

```
class details {
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

int age;
int id;

public details() {
}

public details(String name_, int age_, int id_) {
    name = name_;
    age = age_;
    id = id_;
}
```

// below class actually writed

```
public void writeXmlFile(ArrayList<details> list) {

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder build = dFact.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = build.newDocument();

        Element root = doc.createElement("Studentinfo");
        doc.appendChild(root);

        Element Details = doc.createElement("Details");
        root.appendChild(Details);


        for (details dtl : list) {

            Element name = doc.createElement("Name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(dtl
                    .getName())));
            Details.appendChild(name);

            Element id = doc.createElement("ID");
            id.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(dtl.getId())));
            Details.appendChild(id);

            Element mmi = doc.createElement("Age");
            mmi.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(dtl.getAge())));
            Details.appendChild(mmi);

        }

        // Save the document to the disk file
        TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();

        // format the XML nicely
        aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

        aTransformer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        try {
            // location and name of XML file you can change as per need
            FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("./ros.xml");
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fos);
            aTransformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error outputting document");

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error building document");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is either using XStream or Jackson API (preferred) to serialize the java object to either a XML or a JSON file.

For example, see my [XStream data provider](https://github.com/djangofan/testng-dataprovider-xstream-xml) I wrote for use with TestNG or JUnit parameterized tests.

Answer (score 2):

How about using XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html

Copy and paraphrasing from the javadoc.

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
// populate your array
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(BufferedOutputStream(
                          new FileOutputStream("Test.xml")));
   e.writeObject(arr);
   e.close();
```

Similarly, the reverse to decode.